# Handlebars + React.js: как заставить работать?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, handlebars

В практических целях решил попробовать использовать хэндлбарс с реактом, но никак не могу заставить работать.

К примеру, как данный код сделать рабочим? И есть ли смысл на проекте использовать реакт и хэндлбарс?

```
render: function () {
    var data = this.state.previewData;

   // ??????????
   // Handlebars.compile();

    return <div className="row" id="compile">
                <script type="text/x-handlebars-template">
                      {{CompanyName}}  
                </script>
           </div>
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [React.js + Handlebars: почему появляется ошибка?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454518/react-js-handlebars-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1):

Можно, сама недавно этим баловалась от скуки. А уж стоит или нет, смотри сам.

[Репозиторий на github](https://github.com/stevenvachon/handlebars-react)

---

#### Пример работы плагина

Компилирует это:

```
<div>
    text1
    {{variable1}}
    {{#if variable2}}<span>text2</span>{{else}}text3{{/if}}
    <span data-attr="{{#if variable3}}value1{{/if}} value2">text4</span>
</div>
```

В это:

```
React.DOM.div(null,
    "text1",
    this.props.variable1,
    this.props.variable2 ? React.DOM.span(null,
        "text2"
    ) : "text3",
    React.DOM.span({"data-attr":(this.props.variable3 ? "value1" : "") + " value2"},
        "text4"
    )
);
```

Comment: да там целый парсер, а что в несколько строк нельзя сделать?

Comment: Пока это лучшее из всех возможных решений

Answer (score 0):

Для рендеринга голого HTML есть параметр [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27938353/225767). На самом деле он видимо и предназначен для поддержки нестандартного рендеринга.

Но если вы пишете новый код, не адаптируете legacy, то обходить встроенный метод рендеринга будет совершенно неправильно! Это одна из главных частей Reactа: проигнорировав ее вы выкинете и много полезного.