# React.js + Handlebars: почему появляется ошибка?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, handlebars

Сервер возвращает Handlebars шаблон и json с данными. С помощью реакта я хочу отобразить этот шаблон, предварительно распарсив его Handlebars:

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            previewData: {}, // json данные контекста
            previewHtml: {}  //  Handlebars шаблон
        }
    },

    getTemplateDataStore: function (event, previewData) {
        this.setState({
            previewData: previewData
        });
    },

    getTemplateHTMLStore: function (event, previewHtml) {
        this.setState({
            previewHtml: previewHtml
        });
    },

    render: function () {
        // парсинг шаблона
        var template = Handlebars.compile(this.state.previewHtml);
        var context = {"name": this.state.previewData);

        return <div className="row">
                   {template(context)}
               </div>  

    }   

});
```

Но, проблема в том, что реакт выводит строку, то есть Handlebars вернул к примеру "`<div>John></div>`", реакт так его и отобразил, а ведь нужно же, чтоб это был DOM элемент, в котором находится `John`.

И так же через раз появляется следующая ошибка:

> Error: Invariant Violation: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно отобразить элемент, после парсинга барсом, чтоб не строка выводилась и как пофиксить ошибку?

Answer (score 2):

Давайте по порядку.

**Вставка HTML кода в компоненты React "как есть".**

---

В React.js есть хитрый трюк, позволяющий вставлять HTML разметку в код компонентов как есть. Вам всего лишь нужно присвоить свойству `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` родительского тега JS объект специального вида. Об этом можно почитать в [официальной документации](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html). А вот пример того, как это можно сделать:

```
var App = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        var markup = "<h1>Test</h1>";

        return (<div className="row" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: markup}}>
               </div>);
    }
});

React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/susihukuvu/edit?html,js,console,output)

**Замечание:** Использовать этот трюк следует с особой осторожностью, поскольку вы рискуете столкнуться с XSS. Да и вообще, использование шаблонизаторов в компонентах React это не React-way. Подумайте дважды перед тем, как тащить такое в реальные системы.

**Периодически возникающая ошибка.**

---

Что касается ошибки, то React недвусмысленно дает вам понять, что нельзя изменять состояние компонентов внутри метода `render`. Проверяйте все родительские компоненты на предмет явного или не явного изменения состояния компонентов. (В вашем примере, один из родительских компонентов вполне может вызывать `getTemplateDataStore` или `getTemplateHTMLStore`.)